# Execute NUnit with Jenkins

Tags: c#, nunit, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Good Morning.

I Want to configure Jenkins server to run NUnit with the plugin **Jenkins NUnit plugin** but i try many thing and doesnt works.

I click in the button ** Add a build step** >> **Execute Windows Batch Command**
but i saw here *http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121312/how-do-you-run-nunit-tests-from-jenkins* then i was configuring this form:

"c:\program files\nunit\bin\nunit-console.exe" 
$(project Local)\$(DLLTest).dll

this form return an error but i try this in bat file and nothing happens and i put **start** before first line.
Open the NUnit but nothing happens, in Jenkins the building starting but never ending.

what do i have doing wrong?

Comment: What happens when you launch the commands directly in the command prompt?

Comment: Open the NUnit with de project dll, but doesnt run.

Comment: Your issue is likely with `$(project Local)` and `$(DLLTest)`. Ensure you have defined them properly.

Comment: I do this, i put fixed path. but if was wrong doesnt will open the NUnit with dll, but de NUnit not run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I run it for a specific hard-coded project

"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6\bin\nunit-console.exe" "nUnitTests\bin\Release\nUnitTests.dll" /xml=nunit-result.xml

I needed to specify the xml output to ensure that the Violations plugin (which I'm using) could pick up the output and report correctly which may help you once you've got it working.

Have you tried using %variable% instead of $variable? Within the Windows Batch Command it  uses %WORKSPACE% rather than $WORKSPACE for example. That's what I've done in my FxCop/StyleCop batch commands.

Comment: I got it, but i remove /xml=nunit-result.xml because ununit-console.exe no had this, only xmlConsole