# Jenkins generate nunit report nunit-report.xml

Tags: jenkins, nunit, hudson, jenkins-plugins, nunit-console

I've configured Jenkins to run nunit-console as described here:
[Execute NUnit with Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12748079/execute-nunit-with-jenkins)
and here:
[How do you run NUnit tests from Jenkins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121312/how-do-you-run-nunit-tests-from-jenkins)

I've added "Execute batch command" as a build step and entered the following values:

```
%nunit-console% .\BBA\Sources\Projects\BbaUnitTests\bin\BbaUnitTests.dll /xml=.\BBA\Sources\BuildResults\nunit-result.xml /timeout=10000
```

Everytime I run a build, everything works ok until it gets to this build step,
this line shows up and it runs indefinitely and no xml file is generated:

```
C:\BuildServerFiles\workspace\BBA-71>.\BBA\Sources\Projects\RngUnitTests\bin\BbaUnitTests.dll /xml=.\BBA\Sources\BuildResults\nunit-result.xml /timeout=10000
```

However, when I execute:

```
nunit-console .\BBA\Sources\Projects\BbaUnitTests\bin\BbaUnitTests.dll /xml=.\BBA\Sources\BuildResults\nunit-result.xml /timeout=10000
```

from command prompt it works ok, the xml file gets generated ok. 
What could be the possible issue here?

Comment: Is the Jenkins service running under an account that has access to that directory where you are trying to write the XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added this line to nant build script instead of adding a step to jenkins:

```
formatter type="Xml" outputdir="${main-directory}\BuildResults\" usefile="true" extension=".xml"/>
```

Making it this:

```
<target name="build" description="Build Solution and run tests">
        <echo message="Building the release configuration" />
        <exec program="${msbuild}" commandline='"${my-solution}" /v:m /nologo /property:WarningLevel=0 /t:Rebuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:Platform="Any CPU"' />
        <echo message="Running unit tests" />
        <nunit2>
            <formatter type="Plain" />
            <formatter type="Xml" outputdir="${main-directory}\BuildResults\" usefile="true" extension=".xml"/>
            <test assemblyname="${main-directory}\Projects\MyUnitTests\bin\MyUnitTests.dll">
            </test>
        </nunit2>
    </target>
```