# Build and run unit-tests with two distinct jobs

Tags: jenkins, nunit, jenkins-plugins, nunit-console

I have a basic setup: some source files stored in **GitHub** that are pulled and built by a **Jenkins** job.

Now I'd like to run the **unit-tests** automatically when the build is done (I'm using **NUnit** if it can help).

I could add another **build step** to the "build" job to run **nunit-console** but I'd like to separate the build task from the unit-testing task, so that in the Jenkins dashboard I can directly see what is broken: the build or "only" the tests.

I could create another job that would pull the code-source too but it would duplicate the first job.

What's the simplest way to run the unit-tests directly on the binaries produced by the first job (run second job in the same workspace? copy the binaries? ...) ?

Thanks for any input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy the artefacts to another job and then run the unit tests but this may not work, depending on how C# handles packaging and the project is structured.

It look like you can use the [NUint Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/NUnit+Plugin) to [publish](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9121747/68969) the results of your tests so you may be able to use a single job as I don't think that the tests will run if the previous build step fails as they don't for JUnit tests

Comment: Yes it's what I've done so far. It's more work than expected but seems to work now. Thanks. :)