# Jenkins + NUnit with TFS on Build Server

Tags: tfs, jenkins

I'm new to continuous integration.  I'm trying to get Jenkins to execute unit tests from a TFS project.  My Jenkins build (pre-NUnit build step) is successful and I've installed the NUnit Jenkins plugin and I've read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121312/how-do-you-run-nunit-tests-from-jenkins), but it's failing with this error: "The system cannot find the path specified."

I think the trouble is that I'm NOT running from my local machine, so the test DLL that NUnit should be running is missing I think.  How can I reference that DLL properly?  Do I need an extra Build Step to copy the files or something?  Here's my "Execute Windows Batch Command" build step command:

```
"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe Victoria.Tests.Integration/bin/Debug/Victoria.Tests.Integration.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml"
```

Comment: `C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe` -> `"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe"` to contain the spaces, perhaps?

Comment: I already quoted the path and arguments and NUnit is installed on the build server at the path specified, so I think the problem is the path to the dll.  Thanks for your comment though.

Comment: "Path and arguments" is the key, though, surely? The path and executable should be within quotes, then the space between it and the arguments should be outside the quotes.

Comment: When I UNquote the arguments it works!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your command is all in quotes, including the parameters.

Change

```
"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe Victoria.Tests.Integration/bin/Debug/Victoria.Tests.Integration.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml"
```

to

```
"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.3\bin\nunit-console.exe" Victoria.Tests.Integration/bin/Debug/Victoria.Tests.Integration.dll /xml=nunit-result.xml
```