# UI test automation, build and deployment for C# project

Tags: selenium, deployment, jenkins, msbuild, ui-automation

I have a c# project for which I have written UI Automation using Selenium. I want to know how can I Automate build process along with execution of UI test cases ? On googling, I come to know that Jenkins and MSBuild can do this task. But as I am pretty new to this task, I am not able to get a correct direction of my work. Can some one please share a good link of step by step process for this ?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) servers are created to support this

> Automate build process along with execution of UI test cases

The core functionality that will perform is:

- monitors the repository and checks out changes when they occur
- builds the system and runs unit and integration tests
- releases deployable artefacts for testing
- assigns a build label to the version of the code it just built
- informs the team of the successful build
- after build, alerts the team if it is failed

To help you visualize the workflow:

[image: CI server workflow]

> I come to know that Jenkins and MSBuild can do this task

This is probably not the best option, since there are CI servers designed to work specially with .Net, like [TeamCity](https://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/). All the integration and build-in functionality will make your life easy. [Jenkins](https://jenkins-ci.org/) is more oriented to JAVA apps. I've used both mixed with .Net and JAVA and they work pretty fine, so it's a matter of your choice. Other options are:

- [Bamboo](https://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo)
- [Hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/)

Comment: Thanks @ekostadinov for your answer. I still have one question, let say I have UI Automation tests created using Selenium and I want to execute these test cases on server once build is deployed. How can I run these tests on server automatically ?

Comment: Lets assume you use Jenkins. You're able [to chain jobs](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and-visualizations/). Once deploy and build ones are ready, trigger Selenium one.

Comment: Thanks ekostadinov..I think my question was bit unclear. Actually I got what I wanted and it is NUnit tool which can execute Selenium WebDriver UI test cases. Now I just have to find how I can start test execution in Nunit with automation.

Comment: If it is a NUnit - use the runner [plugin like so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121312/how-do-you-run-nunit-tests-from-jenkins) .

Comment: Thanks..This is exactly what I wanted. :)